# Updating Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, apk

Let me just say I'm not the developer. Is there a way to know if your app needs to be updated? I have an app published with Google and Apple.  Do I have to update the APK every time that Google and Apple releases an new Operating System??

Comment: "Is there a way to know if your app needs to be updated?" -- if it stops working, or crashes a lot, or falls behind competitors, or lacks key features that users are clamoring for, etc. IOW, if the app exists, it probably needs to be updated. "Do I have to update the APK every time that Google and Apple releases an new Operating System?" -- I cannot speak for iOS. On Android, while your code will be backwards-compatible, sometimes there are behavior changes that will affect your app. The details will depend a lot on what the app does.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to update the app automatically anytime Google or Apple updates their os, because in general they are compatible with older apps, but in some cases something breaks up (especially with Android, iOS is generally more stable). so what you have to do is to test your app with the os updates, if it crashes or doesn't work correctly then you should update it.

Comment: My app works fine but on the iOS version, I'm getting this popup message: This app needs to be updated: "This app will not work with future versions of iOS. The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility."  If I click on the Learn More link, it takes me to this message: "These apps may slow down your iPhone and will not work with future versions of iOS if they are not updated. If no update is available, contact the app developer for more information."  I've had this message for a while but the app still works beautifully as expected.

Comment: Are you testing it with the new iOS 11 (which is in beta right now) ? if not you should. But since it's asking you to rebuild it I think you should you can find more informations in this link https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/apr/03/ios-11-apple-latest-update-older-apps-stop-working

Comment: I just found it my app is using 32bit and iOS wants all the apps to switch to 64bit.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a huge undertaking to convert a 32bit app to a 64bit app? Anyone have any ideas in terms of cost?

Comment: it depends on the your code how is it made: you can follow this link to know how to do it exactly https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html